# Unknown error on C++, error: expected primary expression before ';' token

Tags: c++

Unknown error on C++, error: expected primary expression before ';' token. 
Here is the code I wrote in C++:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <math.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #define G 6.674E-11
 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
 //Ms = Mass of sun, Me = Mass of Earth, Fg = Gravitational force between them, As =                                   Acceleration of Sun, Ae = Acceleration of Earth, Ve_x
 // = initial velocity of Earth in x direction, Ve_y = initial velocity of Earth in y          direction, Vs_x = initial velocity of the Sun in x direction
 // Vs_y = initial velocity of sun in y direction, t = time, F = Gravitational force   `    between the two bodies.

    float Ms, Me, Fg, As, Ae, Ve_x, Ve_y, Vs_x, Vs_y, pos_E, pos_S, r_x, r_y, r, t;
    float S_dist;
    float E_dist;
    float F;
    float Ve[2];
    float Vs[2];
    float pe[2];
    float ps[2];


  FILE *fileptr;

    cout <<"Enter mass of the Sun in kg\n";
    cin >> Ms;
    cout <<"Enter mass of the earth in kg\n";
    cin >> Me;
    cout <<"Enter intial velocity of the sun in x direction in m/s\n";
    cin >> Vs[0];
    cout <<"Enter intial velocity of the sun in y direction in m/s\n";
    cin >> Vs[1];
    cout <<"Enter intial velocity of the earth in x direction in m/s\n";
    cin >> Ve[0];
    cout <<"Enter intial velocity of the earth in y direction in m/s\n";
    cin >> Ve[1];
    cout <<"Enter intial position of the sun in x component\n";
    cin >> ps[0];
    cout <<"Enter intial position of the sun in y direction\n";
    cin >> ps[1];
    cout <<"Enter intial position of the earth in x direction\n";
    cin >> pe[0];
    cout <<"Enter intial position of the earth in y direction\n";
    cin >> pe[1];


  for (t=0; t<30000; t+1)
 {
  float E_dist;
  float S_dist;
  float F;

    E_dist=sqrt( ((pe[0]-pe[0])*(pe[0]-pe[0])) + ((pe[1]-pe[1])*(pe[1]-pe[1])) );
    S_dist=sqrt( ((ps[0]-ps[0])*(ps[0]-ps[0])) + ((ps[1]-ps[1])*(ps[1]-ps[1])) );

    r_x=( (pe[0]-pe[0]) - (ps[0]-ps[0]) );
    r_y=( (pe[1]-pe[1]) - (ps[1]-ps[1]) );
    r= sqrt( (r_x)*(r_x) + (r_y)*(r_y) );

    F=(G*Me*Ms)/(r*r);

    Ae = F/Me;
    As = F/Ms;

    Ve_x = Ve[0];
    Ve_y = Ve[1];
    Vs_x = Vs[0];
    Vs_y = Vs[1];
    }
    cout<<"At time "<<t<<":\n The position of the Sun is "<<S_dist<<"\n The position of   the Earth is "<<E_dist
    <<"\n The acceleration of the Sun is "<<As<<" \n The acceleration of the Earth is "<<Ae<<" \nThe velocity of the Sun in the x direction is "
    <<Vs_x<<" \n The velocity of the Sun in the y direction is "<<Vs_y<<" \n The velocity of the Earth in the x direction is "<<Ve_x<<
    " \n The velocity of the Earth in the y direction is "<<Ve_y<<" \n The gravitational force between the Sun and the Earth is "<<F<<; // ERROR OCCURRED HERE.

}
```

Would be grateful for any help, thanks.

Comment: This is wrong (in your loop); `t+1`.  That doesn't change the value of `t`.  It evaluates the expression and throws the result away.  You have an infinite loop.  Also... a floating point number for a loop index variable?

Comment: This has to be one of the most searched problems on Google (+7 million results alone). You'd think compiler writers would just tell you what is wrong.

Comment: Hello @Pat. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thank you for posting your program so that we could find the error. It would have helped even more if you had first deleted all of the lines that didn't have errors on them, leaving a much smaller program for us to examine. See http://sscce.org for more info on this debugging technique. Again, welcome to SO!

Answer (score 8):

I think the error is that your last line ends like this:

```
<<F<<;
```

Notice the `<<` operator is being applied to just one argument.  Did you mean to write something like this?

```
<<F<<endl;
```

For what it's worth, I would **strongly suggest** splitting that output line into multiple lines for clarity.  What you have now is correct, but it's incredibly difficult to read.  Rewriting it as

```
cout << "At time " <<t<<":\n The position of the Sun is "<<S_dist<<"\n";
     << " The position of   the Earth is "<<E_dist << "\n";
     << "The acceleration of the Sun is "<<As<<"\n"
     << "The acceleration of the Earth is "<<Ae<<"\n";
     << "The velocity of the Sun in the x direction is "<<Vs_x<<" \n";
     << "The velocity of the Sun in the y direction is "<<Vs_y<<" \n";
     << "The velocity of the Earth in the x direction is "<<Ve_x<< "\n";
     << "The velocity of the Earth in the y direction is "<<Ve_y<<" \n";
     << "The gravitational force between the Sun and the Earth is "<<F<<;
```

would have made this error much easier to spot, since the line numbering information would be more useful.  Also, I would suggest adding spaces in-between the `<<` operators to make it a bit easier to read.

Comment: The extra cout's are not necessary FYI and would be more readable without.

Comment: Agreed, I would just keep the operators and forget all the different statements.

Answer (score 5):

[templatetypedef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/501557/templatetypedef) has pointed out the compiler error, but there is another problem in the code: 
the `for` loop is infinite:

```
for (t=0; t<30000; t+1)
```

should be:

```
for (t=0; t<30000; t++)
```

or as `t` is a `float`, based on [Is using increment (operator++) on floats bad style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561393/is-using-increment-operator-on-floats-bad-style):

```
for (t = 0; t < 30000; t+=1.0f)
```

Comment: This is true, but the OPs error is a compile time error. +1 anyways (even though this is not the answer to the question)

Comment: Good find, but does not fix his problem (could have turned into another question derived from this one) +1

Comment: @Marlon, I know it does not answer the question. Referenced an answer that does correct the compiler error though.

Comment: pfft, whatever, I noticed it first and left a comment :D

Comment: @EdS., never noticed your comment, was typing this up at the time.

Answer (score 0):

your first syntax error is because of having another `<<` at the end of statement `cout<<F<<;` just change it to `cout<<F;` unless you have another var to print or you want to use endline like: `cout<<F<<endl;`.

you have another one syntax error too!
your `main` returns int but you didn't returned anything at the end:

`return 0;`

**Another very very very important issue is about the variable `F`!**

**Logical error!!!**

```
int main()
{
....
  float S_dist; //real S_dist !!!
  float E_dist; //real E_dist !!!
  float F;      //real F !!!
  for (t=0; t<30000; t++)
  {

     float F; // just exists in for!!!
     float E_dist; //just exists in for!!!
     float E_dist; //just exists in for!!!
  ....
     F=(G*Me*Ms)/(r*r); //changing local F, which just exists in for
     E_dist=sqrt( ((pe[0]-pe[0])*(pe[0]-pe[0])) + ((pe[1]-pe[1])*(pe[1]-pe[1])) );
     S_dist=sqrt( ((ps[0]-ps[0])*(ps[0]-ps[0])) + ((ps[1]-ps[1])*(ps[1]-ps[1])) );
  }
  cout<<F<<E_dist<<S_dist; //this prints the main vars!
  return 0;
}
```

be sure to read about local variables more.
and keep in mind that `t+1` doesn't change the `t` at all! you should write `t++` or `t+=1` in the last part of the `for` statement instead! unless you will get an infinite loop, cause your `t` does not grow at all!