# Returning a double value in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to make a program which gives me the sum of series 1!+2/2!+3/3!...........n/n!
Here's my code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int n;

double sumseries(double sum, double count)
{
    double fac = 1, i;
    for (i = 1; i <= count; i++)
        fac = fac*i;

    sum += (count++ / fac);
    if (count <= n)
        sumseries(sum, count);
    else {
        printf("sum of series is:%lf", sum);
        return sum;
    }
}

int main()
{
    printf("enter the limit");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    double z = sumseries(0,1);
    printf("\n%lf",z);
    system("pause");
 }
```

Now when we print sum from the sumseries() function, correct value is printed. But in the very next line we return the sum and save it in z variable in main() function. And when we try to print that value, it shows -nan(ind)

My question is not how to solve this problem or how to make this program work. What I'm asking is what is causing this problem in the code above. Why isn't correct value being returned.

Comment: Turn your compiler's warnings to higher level. It will immediately tell you. You have recursion but you don't do `return`s through the whole chain. Or run the code in a debugger line by line and you'll see what happens.

Comment: I didn't know there were a postfix increment on doubles. Who uses that?

Comment: According to [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8561459/5470596), using `double++` repeatedly adds up errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `sumseries` function, not all flow control path returns a value.

You should, at least, write

```
if (count <= n)
    return sumseries(sum, count);
```

instead of

```
if (count <= n)
    sumseries(sum, count);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler should give you a warning, or even an error for the problem. If not, please turn the warning level higher.

You have a *recursive* function sumseries but you don't return a value from all paths that lead to the end. Therefore the return value is indetermined.

A recursive function doesn't just return once, you have to return from each step. In this case you return the last value, but the previous call to the function throws it away. You need to keep returning it. Therefore you need to use

```
return sumseries(sum, count);
```

to keep returning the value to the previous step.

Answer (score 0):

Control flow in sumseries() may reach its end and return undefined value. You need to make such situation impossible in your code. Probably you want to use this statement:

```
if (count <= n)
    return sumseries(sum, count);
```

instead of merely

```
if (count <= n)
       sumseries(sum, count);
```