# (Operating System) How can I use __asm mfence in c

Tags: c, winapi, memory, operating-system, barrier

I'm taking an operating system class and my professor gave us this homework.

"Place __asm mfence in a proper position."

This problem is about using multiple threads and its side-effect.

Main thread is increasing shared_var but thread_1 is doing it in the same time.

Thus, shared_var becomes 199048359.000 when the code is increasing number 2000000 times.

The professor said __asm mfence will solve this issue. But, I do not know where to place it.

I'm trying to search the problem on google, github and here but I cannot find a source.

I do not know this is a stupid question because I'm not majoring in computer science.

Also, I would like to know why this code shows 199948358.0000 not 2000000.00

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

int turn;
int interested[2];
void EnterRegion(int process);
void LeaveRegion(int process);

DWORD WINAPI thread_func_1(LPVOID lpParam);
 volatile  double   shared_var = 0.0;
volatile int    job_complete[2] = {0, 0};


int main(void)
{
    DWORD dwThreadId_1, dwThrdParam_1 = 1; 
    HANDLE hThread_1; 
    int     i, j;

    // Create Thread 1
    hThread_1 = CreateThread( 
        NULL,                        // default security attributes 
        0,                           // use default stack size  
        thread_func_1,                  // thread function 
        &dwThrdParam_1,                // argument to thread function 
        0,                           // use default creation flags 
        &dwThreadId_1
        );                // returns the thread identifier 

   // Check the return value for success. 

    if (hThread_1 == NULL) 
    {
       printf("Thread 1 creation error\n");
       exit(0);
    }
    else 
    {
       CloseHandle( hThread_1 );
    }

    /* I am main thread */
    /* Now Main Thread and Thread 1 runs concurrently */

    for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) 
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 10000; j++) 
        {
            EnterRegion(0);
            shared_var++;
            LeaveRegion(0);
        }
    }

    printf("Main Thread completed\n");
    job_complete[0] = 1;
    while (job_complete[1] == 0) ;

    printf("%f\n", shared_var);
    _getch();
    ExitProcess(0);
}


DWORD WINAPI thread_func_1(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    int     i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 10000; j++) 
        {
            EnterRegion(1);
            shared_var++;
            LeaveRegion(1);
        }
    }

    printf("Thread_1 completed\n");
    job_complete[1] = 1;
    ExitThread(0);
}


void EnterRegion(int process)
{
    _asm mfence;
    int other;

    other = 1 - process;
    interested[process] = TRUE;
    turn = process;
    while (turn == process && interested[other] == TRUE) {}
    _asm mfence;
}

void LeaveRegion(int process)
{
    _asm mfence;
    interested[process] = FALSE;
    _asm mfence;
}
```

Comment: You could have mentioned the win32 tag instead of the wider operating-system tag. You might also want to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8561459/8155816, there doesn't seem to be an answer but a lot of discussion was made revolving around it.

Comment: @alc: That answer does not apply here. `shared_var` is initialized to `0.0` and always incremented by exactly `1.0`. That will *always* produce a floating point value without a fractional part. A floating point value can accurately represent any non-fractional number (within its range). `2000000.00` is well within the range of non-fractional numbers a `double` can accurately represent.

Comment: Thus why I said the comments and surrounding conversations, rather than the answer, might be interesting. ^^'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `EnterRegion()` and `LeaveRegion()` functions are implementing a critical region using a thing called "Peterson's algorithm".

Now, the key to Peterson's algorithm is that when a thread reads `turn` it **must** get the latest (most recent) value written by **any** thread.  That is, operations on `turn` must be Sequentially Consistent.  Also, the write to `interested[]` in `EnterRegion()` must become visible to all threads before (or at the same time) as the write to `turn`.

So the place to put the `mfence` is after the `turn = process ;` -- so that the thread does not proceed until its write to `turn` is visible to all other threads.

It is also important to persuade the compiler to read from memory every time it reads `turn` and `interested[]`, so you should set them `volatile`.

If you are writing this for x86 or x86_64, that is sufficient -- because they are generally "well behaved", so that:

- all the writes to `turn` and `interested[process]` will occur in program order
- all the reads of `turn` and `interested[other]` will also occur in program order

and setting those `volatile` ensures that the compiler doesn't fiddle with the order, either.

The reason for using the `mfence` on the x86 and x86_64 in this case is to flush the write queue to memory before proceeding to read the `turn` value.  So, all memory writes go into a queue, and at some time in the future each write will reach actual memory, and the effect of the write will become visible to other threads -- the write has "completed".  Writes "complete" in the same order the program did them, but delayed.  If the thread reads something it has written recently, the processor will pick the (most recent) value out of the write queue.  This means that the thread does not need to wait until the write "completes", which is generally a Good Thing.  However, it does mean that the thread is *not* reading the same value that any other thread will read, at least until the write does "complete".  What the `mfence` does is to stall the processor until all outstanding writes have "completed" -- so any following reads will read the same thing any other thread would read.

The write to `interested[]` in `LeaveRegion()` does not (on x86/x86_64) require an `mfence`, which is good because `mfence` is a costly operation.  Each thread only ever writes to its own `interested[]` flag and only ever reads the other's.  The only constraint on this write is that it must *not* "complete" *after* the write in `EnterRegion()` (!).  Happily the x86/x86_64 does all writes in order.  [Though, of course, after the write in `LeaveRegion()` the write in `EnterRegion()` may "complete" before the other thread reads the flag.]

For other devices, you might want other fences to enforce the ordering of reads/writes of `turn` and `interested[]`.  But I don't pretend to know enough to advise on ARM or POWERPC or anything else.

Comment: Thank you so much Chris!!! It works fine now and you got me some great advises!