# Unity Variable gets Infinity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just wanted to use simple math in my script, but as soon as I start it, "Percent Red" gets infinity. Ive researched and I found out that it can be caused by a DivisionByZero, but I don't know what I did wrong, I have tried everything I could.

```
void Start(){
    RedClick = 10;
    BlueClick = 10;
}

void Update()
{
    AllClicks = RedClick + BlueClick;
    Percent = AllClicks / 100;
    PercentRed = RedClick / Percent;
    RedFill.fillAmount = PercentRed;
}

public void RedButton(){ RedClick++; }
public void BlueButton(){ BlueClick++; }
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can just guess but from your results and ho you use them I'd assume that all of these `RedClick`, `BlueClick`, `Percent`, `AllClicks` are of type `int`.

So, what you get is an [**Integer division!**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#division-operator-) For `int` values the `/` is without decimals!

=> as long as `AllClicks < 100` you get

```
Percent = 0;
```

and then

```
PercentRed = RedClick / 0;
```

division by `0` in general is not too good ;)

---

simple fix: Use **float** division!

So your field `Percent` should be a `float`

```
float Percent;
```

and then use the post-fix [`f` literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types#real-literals) to use a `float` instead of an integer `decimal` (default in `c#` without specifier) for your value `100`

```
Percent = AllClicks / 100f;
```

Comment: but am I still able todo RedClick++ then ?

Comment: @Mcrft Of course (see [`++` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#increment-operator-)) using `x++;` basically just equals using `x += 1;` .. see also [Is using increment (operator++) on floats bad style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561393/is-using-increment-operator-on-floats-bad-style)

Comment: @derHugo I don't think you're suggesting to change the `RedClick` or `BlueClick` values from `int` to `float`, though, so the topic of using `++` on a float is somewhat moot.

Comment: @J... oh yeah that's true actually ^^ shouldn't jump between questions too much :D